# SPSS: Having a hard time creating a set of variables using LOOP and COMPUTE

Tags: spss

I'm trying to create a set of variables using LOOP and COMPUTE but having a hard time. When I run the code below, I get 3 bugs below. These correspond to the Bolded STRING and the indented COMPUTE commands below the string:

- Command: STRING "The format specified is not recognized. Text: #H"
- Command: COMPUTE "An equals sign was not found when expected after a
  target variable in a COMPUTE command. Text: (
- Command: COMPUTE "An equals sign was not found when expected after a
  target variable in a COMPUTE command. Text: (

Basically my goal is to create a series of variables GLD_935  GLD_940   GLD_945 etc. But it's not creating the variables. Any ideas?

```
DATASET ACTIVATE  GLD_5.    
STRING H2 (A2).    
STRING M2 (A2).    
STRING X (A5).    
STRING Y (A8).    
LOOP #H = 9 TO 14 BY 1.    
LOOP #M = 00 TO 55 BY 5.    
   COMPUTE H2 = STRING(#H,F2.0).
   IF (LENGTH(H2) = 1) H2 = CONCAT("0",H2).    
   COMPUTE M2 = STRING(#M,F2.0).    
   IF (LENGTH(M2) = 1) M2 = CONCAT("0",M2).    
   COMPUTE X = CONCAT(H2,":",M2).    
   **STRING GLD_(#H)(#M) (A8).**    
   DO IF (TIME = X).    
      **COMPUTE GLD_(#H)(#M) = GLD5_Close.**
   END IF.    
   DO IF (TIME ~= X).    
      **COMPUTE  GLD_(#H)(#M) = LAG(Y,1).**     
   END IF.    
END LOOP.
END LOOP.
EXECUTE.
```

Comment: My edit wasn't accepted but to avoid confusion - the double asterisk in the code posted by the OP are to signify **BOLD** font (bold font is not accepted in code by SO) and _not_ SPSS comments which are syntactically represented by starting a line with an asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can double index [VECTORS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_vector.htm) as you are attempting to do so here (also they need to be initialised beforehand):

```
STRING GLD_(#H)(#M) (A8).
```

Therefore, I would be inclined to do this using SPSS macro functionality, [DEFINE / !ENDDEFINE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_define.htm) or SPSS integrated Python Programmability. I give an example below, though not attempting to replicate exactly your requirements but still nonetheless giving you enough to adapt to your needs.

```
DATASET CLOSE ALL.
OUTPUT CLOSE ALL.
NEW FILE.
DATA LIST FREE / ID (F8.0) TIME (A1).
BEGIN DATA.
1 1
2 2 
11 1
12 2
END DATA.
DATASET NAME DSRaw.

/* Note you can create a string with leading zeros, taking advantage of the N format */.
STRING IDStr (A2).
COMPUTE IDStr=STRING(ID, N2).

DEFINE !RunJob ()
!DO !h = 9 !TO 14

  !IF (!LEN(!h)=1) !THEN
    !LET !hpad=!CONCAT("0",!h)
  !ELSE
    !LET !hpad=!h
  !IFEND

  !DO !m = 0 !TO 55 !BY 5

    !IF (!LEN(!m)=1) !THEN
      !LET !mpad=!CONCAT("0",!m)
    !ELSE
      !LET !mpad=!m
    !IFEND

    IF (TIME = CONCAT(STRING(!h,N2),":",STRING(!m,N2))) !CONCAT("GLD_",!hpad,"_",!mpad)=1.

  !DOEND
!DOEND
!ENDDEFINE.


SET MPRINT ON.
!RunJob.
SET MPRINT OFF.
```

And here's an equivalent python solution:

```
BEGIN PROGRAM PYTHON.
for h in xrange(9,15):
    for m in xrange(0,56,5):
        spss.Submit("""IF (TIME = '%(h)02d:%(m)02d') GLD_%(h)02d_%(m)02d=1.""" % locals())
END PROGRAM.
```

Comment: Hi Jignesh  I appreciate your advice and code. I am going to need to play around with this before I know if it's successful. Thanks so much!  Adam

Comment: Hi Jignesh  Ok I used your SPSS coding, obviously with some changes and it really works great (all of the variables are created for me now). There is one question I have left. It has to do with this command in your Macro loop:  !CONCAT("GLD_",!h,!m)=1.   Basically I can't get the !m to resolve with a leading "0". So this causes it to work incorrectly if if !m = 00 or 05.   For example, if time is 915 it will show 915, if time is 900 it will show 90 and if time is 905 it will show 95.

Comment: So I tried to apply the same technique you did to change the !CONCAT as follows: !CONCAT("GLD_",!h,!STRING(!m,N2))=1. - but that didn't help because  for some reason i'm getting a problem with my DEFINE command now (In a macro expression, a left parenthesis immediately follows and operand. Text: (    Sorry this seems so trivial but I am new to macro language in SPSS. Anyt thoughts?  Thanks so much! Adam

Comment: This didn't work either: !CONCAT("GLD_",!h,!CHAR.LPAD(!m,2,0))=1.

Comment: For this very reason I would encourage you to take up Python, at the very least study the Python solution I provided rather than the SPSS Macro, as what you are trying to achieve is far far easier with Python programming. I have nonetheless update my original post to answer your question.

Comment: i understand... i bought my SPSS License about 5 years ago; version 18. i don't think i'm licensed for Python as it wouldn't accept any of that code; that was the only reason i used the SPSS functionality. Ok, i appreciate your time very much; i'll go try and apply it.   thanks again.. adam